# How to create PNG templates with Python

Tags: python, image, templates

How would I go about creating PNG templates that I could pass data or information to so that it would show in the Image? For clarification, I'm thinking of something similar to how [GitHub README Stats](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats) works, but with PNGs instead of SVGs. Or how widgets work for Discord's Widget Images (e.g. https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/guildID/widget.png?style=banner1).

If there isn't a library for this kind of thing what would it take to make one? (I need a time sink, so I'm pretty keen on making something, even if it only fits my needs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont #Import PIL functions
class myTemplate(): #Your template
    def __init__(self, name, description, image):
        self.name=name #Saves Name input as a self object
        self.description=description #Saves Description input as a self object
        self.image=image #Saves Image input as a self object
    def draw(self):
        """
        Draw Function
        ------------------ 
        Draws the template
        """
        img = Image.open(r'C:\foo\...\template.png', 'r').convert('RGB') #Opens Template Image
        if self.image != '':
            pasted = Image.open(self.image).convert("RGBA") #Opens Selected Image
            pasted=pasted.resize((278, int(pasted.size[1]*(278/pasted.size[0])))) #Resize image to width fit black area's width
            pasted=pasted.crop((0, 0, 278, 322)) #Crop height
            img.paste(pasted, (31, 141)) #Pastes image into template
            imgdraw=ImageDraw.Draw(img) #Create a canvas
        font=ImageFont.truetype("C:/Windows/Fonts/Calibril.ttf", 48) #Loads font
        imgdraw.text((515,152), self.name, (0,0,0), font=font) #Draws name
        imgdraw.text((654,231), self.description, (0,0,0), font=font) #Draws description

        img.save(r'C:\foo\...\out.png') #Saves output

amaztemp=myTemplate('Hello, world!', 'Hi there', r'C:\foo\...\images.jfif')
amaztemp.draw()
```

## Explanation

PIL is an Image Manipulation library, it can edit images like GIMP with Python (but its more limited).

In this code we declare a class called `myTemplate`, that will be our template, inside this class we have two functions, one will initialize the class, and request `name`, `description` and `image`, and the other will draw.

Well, from line `13` to `15`, the program imports and verifies if there is a selected image, if yes it crops and resizes the selected image (`16` and `17`), then pastes the selected image in the template.

After this, name and description are drawn, then the program saves the file.

You can customize teh class and the line `26` for your needs

## Image references

### template.png

[image: template.png]

### images.jfif

[image: images.jfif]

### out.png

[image: out.png]

Comment: Thanks for this, both the explanation and code sample were just what I needed.